# Python how to print a list more than once but in order?

Tags: python

I have code that adds numbers to a list that are within a range determined by user input.

```
user_input = input("Enter a min integer: ")
minInt = int(user_input)

user_input = input("Enter a max integer: ")
maxInt = int(user_input)

num_range = range(minInt,maxInt+1)
num_list = list(num_range)
print("Here is a list of numbers constructed: " + str(num_list))
```

at the moment it works as follows. if the user enters 5 and 7 then the output produced is
`Here is a list of numbers constructed: [5, 6, 7]`

My goal, however, is to print each element of the list three times in order. So the above output would instead look like the following
`Here is a list of numbers constructed: [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7]`where each element has been printed a total of 3 times

Comment: `sorted(num_list * 3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with list comprehension

```
lst = [5, 6, 7] 
newList = [num for num in lst for i in range(3)]
```